# Django best practices

Tags: django, django-templates

I am wondering if I am doing the right thing on my project organisation:

For now each app has its template folder containing html files.

Also each app has its own static file containing JS files and CSS files (one per html), is it what we do, "in best practices" 1html=1css?

Then I also have common stuff, for example navbar, or footer html in a main folder located at the root of my project.

I have seen several practices, but I am not able to tell which one is better.

Thank you

Comment: There's no one true best answer. It always depends. That said, pick up Two Scoops of Django by the Feldroy's. It's a quality book on best practices. Also, check out forum.djangoproject.com

Answer (score 1):

There are not real 'best practice' on file management since it varies depending on personal preferences. So the I believe the more important thing is to find a structure which makes you feel comfortable and easy to work with.

In general there are 2 types,

one is in a Django convention, we will **separate templates and static files in each *app***, for example:

```sh
.
├── app1
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── ulrs.py
```

Even if you do not add any directories in your `STATICFILES_DIRS` in `settings.py`, Django finders app will look for those `static` and `templates` folders **in each app folder by default**.

Thus if you try to find an 'official approach', this might be the case -- please do not get me wrong, this does not mean a 'best practice', for some people it is weird to look for a template in a dir like `app1/templates/app1/items.html`.

The other one is **gathering templates and static files** and put them in root directory folders. For example:

```sh
.
├── project_folder
├── manage.py
├── media
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── icons
│   ├── img
│   ├── js
│   └── vendor
└── templates
    ├── app1
    ├── app2
    ├── base.html
```

This requires further customization on your `settings.py`, for example:

```py
# settings.py
# tell django to find static files in the root directory 'static' folder
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
#...
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # here tells django to find templates in the root directory 'templates' folder
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    #...
    },
]

# views.py
class ItemIListView(ListView):
    model = Item
    context_object_name = 'items'
    # here will look for templates in you 'app1' folder in 'templates'
    template_name = 'app1/item-list.html'
```

And in your templates to load static files, may look like something below:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app1/css/app1.css' %}" />
```

Another considerable reason of these 2 types of approach, I think it **depends on your projects scale**. If you only have like 3 or 5 apps in your project, gathering those templates and static files may make your file structure look cleaner. However, as your project grows, it will be a headache to put everything together, comparing with leaving them in each *app*.

Therefore as a conclusion, **follow the way which makes you feel comfortable**, either the convention or customize on your own way is fine. [Here](https://studygyaan.com/django/best-practice-to-structure-django-project-directories-and-files) is a gathering approach example as your reference.